# score submittion failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gamekit

I am receiving always a Failure in my cocos2d, but when I run this project in my view based application then it will give me success, and the score will easily submitted

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if (error ==nil) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Fail");
    }   
}];


GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"123"] autorelease];
myScoreValue.value =  lastScore;

[myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the GameKit framework, and also; where have you placed the code?

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){ if (error ==nil) { NSLog(@"Success"); } else { NSLog(@"Fail"); }

}];
```

You have to authenticate when the user starts the app, or when the viewDidLoad function is called.

I don't think I really understand what your problem is. What warnings do you geT?

Comment: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=2 "The requested operation has been cancelled." UserInfo=0x232d10 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation has been cancelled.}

Answer (score 6):

I had this error, too. I think it happens when you're logged into a regular gamecenter acct and try to autenticate with an app that needs to be sandboxed. But I'm not sure of that, that's just a guess.

What worked for me was to go and log out with the Game Center app, and then try the app again, and that will login or create a sandboxed user.

Not the most descriptive error message ever though.

Comment: I was having issues in simulator whereas my gamecenter code worked fine in the devices. Problem turns out to be what joeld said, simulator was already hooked up to an account giving error everytime I tried to connect. Easy way log in to your gamecenter account by opening with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]]; then log out and comment the url code. It might help your situation also