# iPhone Simulator 6.0 not able to connect to gamecenter in sandbox mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios-simulator, game-center

I'm trying to implement a gamecenter aware app targeted to iOS 6. To give some info on the environment I'm working on mac os 10.7.5 with XCode version is 4.5.2 and xcode is running iphone and ipad simulator version 6.0. The problem is I cannot connect to gamecenter in sandbox mode neither through ipad or iphone simulator, but the same code works as desired while testing in my iphone.

I followed the gamecenter programming guide in apple's developer library and I got this atm it is called from applicationDidFInishLaunching in appdelegate:

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser:(UIViewController *)currentViewController
{

    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){

        if (viewController != nil)
        {
            [currentViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
        {
            NSLog(@"Player authenticated");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Player not authenticated");
        }
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    };
}
```

It outputs:

```
Error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=2 "The requested operation has been cancelled."
UserInfo=0x8690510 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operation has been cancelled.}

GKSConnSettings: set server: {
        "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
        "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
        "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
        "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
    }
```

I already tried hosts file fix though my OS is not 10.8.2 but it didn't help. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/168811?tstart=0

Any idea what can be the possible cause?

Edit: Well, it turns out the output part starting with GKSConnSettings does not indicate any problems, that's the regular output while connecting to game center as I understood from what I read over internet.  I printed the actual error message (GKErrorDomain = 2 ...) inside the authentication block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the inspiration from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8115807/837244, and decided to log in to game center account with a different piece of code. So in viewdidload I normally called:

```
[[GCHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser:self];
```

Now I commented that out, accessed game center through below URL scheme, logged in to my account and after that logged out.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"gamecenter:"]];
```

And lastly reverted back by commenting out URL code and using the original code. Now it works fine, I guess the problem was that a game center account was already hooked up in simulator and it denied every login request bc of that. Hope apple goes clearer with error messages, it took a month to fix such a simple issue, may this help to others.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question references specific Xcode and iOS simulation versions, but if your simulator is already logged in one account, and you don't mind losing whatever data you've got on the simulator (chances are small, but you never know), you can simply reset the settings and data on it.

Go to:
Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

...and confirm the action when prompted.

This is certainly true for Xcode7.x running an iOS 9.x simulator, someone else might be able to verify whether it's true for earlier versions (especially as I've unearthed quite an old question and answer).

### Animal451

Necrothreadomancy: +1