# ios7 can't get login in gamecenter gain after cancel 3 times

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, game-center

The problem is strange. My system version is IOS7. Everything goes fine on ios7 simulator. However, when I try authenticate on my iphone, the error in the callback block is always **`"GkErrorCanceled: the requested operation has been canceled or disabled by the user".`** 
Even if I've already logged in game center, the error still pops.
I tried google the problem, and find someone on stackoverflow had conquered the issue:
 [iPhone Simulator 6.0 not able to connect to gamecenter in sandbox mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095993/iphone-simulator-6-0-not-able-to-connect-to-gamecenter-in-sandbox-mode). 
I tried following the way, however, it didn't work for me. I don't know if I did anything wrong.
Could some one give me a more detailed solution on this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you have cancel game center login dialog 3 times. Same thing is happening for me too

Comment: Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: It happend to me too, and on a device with iOS 6 it asks me to login to game center but on a device with ios7,on which i have canceled it a few times i get the same error message as you do.

Comment: You just need to go to settings -> login to game center. -> launch your app. (you'll see the login banner on app launch). go to settings again -> logout from game center -> launch your app -> you'll be able see the game center login =).

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**
This issue appears to happen in sandbox only.

Got this problem too, and here what I've figured out:

GameCenter shows prompt for login only a few times (3-5), if all prompts were canceled - GameCenter becomes disabled for this app.

In iOS 7 there is a problem: **GameCenter disabled state remains even if you login into the GameCenter app itself** - application will still receive kind of this error:

`error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=2 GkErrorCanceled: the requested operation has been canceled or disabled by the user`

There are two workarounds:

First:

1. Log out of Game Center through the Settings app.
2. Reset all settings
3. After the device rebooted, launch app with development build. After launch the GC Login viewController pops up.

Second (this one helped me):

1. "Erase All Content And Settings".
2. Set up as a new device - do not restore from any backups.

Both workarounds are not a viable option for production - I hope there will be a fix from Apple soon.

Most of the info is from to this **[discussion](https://devforums.apple.com/message/865906)**.

Comment: I found that this issue is only with sandbox. In live it is working fine.

Comment: I also found that when user press disable button, no any event or method fires. Not even authantication block return anything.

Comment: looking forward to fix from Apple on this...

Comment: any have an update from Apple

Answer (score 2):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings

(i read this somewhere but if the user has to do the same its not a good solution)
(i did this for a app that i am testing , not a app gone live on the App Store) i tested for a n app from the appstore(not mine) and i couldnt reproduce the problem i mean after i logged back from settings i was logged back in that app.

But for app i am testing, only reseting worked . I just saw a new ios update is available maybe that will fix it .

Comment: This works, but keep in mind you need to reenter your wifi password if you aren't connected to a mobile network with your test phone. Otherwise gamecenter won't show up when you run your app. Resetting your phone removes wifi password.